# Scroll up to the top on click

Tags: javascript, scroll

Im trying to bring the scroll up when different sections clicked (portfolio, about me etc.) I know I have to use window.scrollTo(0, 0); but im not sure where to put it to make it work

```js
const sections = document.querySelectorAll(".section");
const sectBtns = document.querySelectorAll(".controls");
const sectBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".control");
const allSections = document.querySelectorAll(".main-content");

function PageTransitions() {
  // Button click active class
  for (let i = 0; i < sectBtn.length; i++) {
    sectBtn[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
      let currentBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".active-btn");
      currentBtn[0].className = currentBtn[0].className.replace(
        "active-btn",
        ""
      );
      this.className += " active-btn";
    });
  }

  //Sections Active
  allSections[0].addEventListener("click", e => {
    const id = e.target.dataset.id;
    if (id) {
      //   //remove selected from the other btns
      sectBtns.forEach(btn => {
        btn.classList.remove("active");
      });
      e.target.classList.add("active");

      //hide other sections
      sections.forEach(section => {
        section.classList.remove("active");
      });

      const element = document.getElementById(id);
      element.classList.add("active");
    }
  });
}

PageTransitions();
```

Comment: You have 2 `click` event handlers, so it seems you'd have 50% chance make it work on first try by adding it at the end of one of the handlers and 100% chance of success on second try...